# c# pass in data formatting string at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-formatting

i would like to be able to pass in a format string at runtime and have it applied against a nominal data value.

for example, the incoming format string could look anything like the standard c# format types:

{0:c}, {0:d}, #,###,###

i want to be able to accept the string value and apply the format at runtime. some pseudocode

```
private string FormatAtRunTime(formatstring)
{
   string formattedOutput = "";
   decimal datavalue = 2.4600;

   datavalue.ToString(formatstring);   ??????

   return formattedOutput;
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem, exactly? Have you tried something?

Comment: what issue are you experiencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
string formattedOutput = string.Format(formatstring, datavalue);
```

The fact that the first argument isn't a string literal (as most calls to `Format` probably are) is irrelevant.

Note that calling `datavalue.ToString(formatstring)` would be fine if `formatstring` were a *single* format specifier, e.g. "c" or even "0.000" - but it can't be a *composite* format string as your example gives. For that, you need `string.Format`.

Comment: good guess, but in any case a good explanation about `data.ToString()` and ´String.Format()` :)